Filter function according variable value failed
Below code when filter_variable  are in  E I J H F G D, it's working well, but when filter_variable <- 'ALL' can't get the result. How to fix it or apply another replacement?
library(tidyverse)
filter_variable <- 'ALL'
diamonds %>% filter(color %in% ifelse(filter_variable =='ALL',
                                     diamonds$color %>% unique() ,
                                     filter_variable)
                                     )


The ifelse() function isn't particularly helpful in this situation; if you use if_else() instead you get an error that describes the problem:
library(tidyverse)
filter_variable <- 'ALL'
diamonds %>% filter(color %in% if_else(filter_variable =='ALL',
                                      diamonds$color %>% unique() ,
                                      filter_variable)
)
#> Error in `filter()`:
#> ℹ In argument: ``%in%`(...)`.
#> Caused by error in `if_else()`:
#> ! `true` must have size 1, not size 7.

A potential solution for this issue (seven 'things' returned instead of one) is to use an 'if else' statement, e.g.
diamonds %>%
  filter(color %in% if(filter_variable == 'ALL'){diamonds$color %>% unique()} else {filter_variable})
#> # A tibble: 53,940 × 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#>  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#>  5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#>  7  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#>  8  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#>  9  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#> 10  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
#> # ℹ 53,930 more rows

Created on 2024-10-08 with reprex v2.1.0

I think a conditional filter step like below is easier to read.
library(tidyverse)
#filter_variable <- 'E'
filter_variable <- 'ALL' 
diamonds %>% 
  {
    if(filter_variable != 'ALL'){
      filter(., color %in% filter_variable)
    }else{.}
  }
#> # A tibble: 53,940 × 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#>  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#>  5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#>  6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#>  7  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#>  8  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#>  9  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
#> 10  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
#> # ℹ 53,930 more rows

Created on 2024-10-08 with reprex v2.1.1
Why your code isn't working as expected: according to ?ifelse() the return value is "A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class")
as test and data values from the values of yes or no. " (with notation ifelse(test, yes, no)).
Thus, in this case the length of your output is 1.
Things get even harder since color is an ordered factor which internally is stored as integer.
diamonds$color %>% unique() 
#> [1] E I J H F G D
#> Levels: D < E < F < G < H < I < J

Since the first value of this vector is E which is the second level
your ifelse evaluates to 2 and the filtering result has 0 rows.
You can see that if you swap unique() for levels() which returns characters. Again, length one, but this time it's the first level and you filter for all observations with color == 'D'.
library(tidyverse)
filter_variable <-  'ALL' # 'E'#
diamonds %>% 
  filter(color %in% ifelse(filter_variable == 'ALL',
                           diamonds$color %>% levels() ,
                           filter_variable)
)
#> # A tibble: 6,775 × 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.23 Very Good D     VS2      60.5    61   357  3.96  3.97  2.4 
#>  2  0.23 Very Good D     VS1      61.9    58   402  3.92  3.96  2.44
#>  3  0.26 Very Good D     VS2      60.8    59   403  4.13  4.16  2.52
#>  4  0.26 Good      D     VS2      65.2    56   403  3.99  4.02  2.61

